# Jquery ajax upload not showing values for the big images?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a page where i have send form data using jquery ajax upload and in php file i am posting these values in database but it is not showing any values for big image in php files when i try to print . Please check with the my screen shot. upload image size 2mb

```
var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
formData.append('licens_certificate', licens_certificate);

$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>pro/submit_business",
    type: "POST",
    data:formData,
    async: false,   
    processData : false,
    contentType : false,
    // fileElementId   :'licens_certificate',
    dataType: "json",   
    // contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
    success: function(result){
        alert()
    }
});
```

[image: no response in php file]
[image: response]

Comment: For starters, you should add an `error` function to display an error in the console

Comment: @cl3m it is not showing the values.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**  Here's how you convert your form to JSON:

```
var serializeJSON = function(formData) {
    var jsonData = {};
    $.each(formData, function() {
        if (jsonData[this.name]) {
            if (!jsonData[this.name].push) {
                jsonData[this.name] = [jsonData[this.name]];
            }
            jsonData[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            jsonData[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return jsonData;
}

var formData = $("#myform").serializeArray();
var json = serializeJSON(formData);

// Add your licens_certificate data
json['licens_certificate' = 'licens_certificate';

$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>pro/submit_business",
    type: "POST",
    data: json,
    async: false,   
    processData : false,
    contentType : false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result){
        alert()
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

**Original**

Have you tried to serialize your form?

```
var formData = $('form').serializeArray();
formData.push({licens_certificate:, 'licens_certificate'});

$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>pro/submit_business",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    async: false,   
    processData : false,
    contentType : false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result){
        alert()
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Also, make sure you are serializing the right form, especialy if you have several in your page.

You could also simply use the `$.post` function

```
var url = "<?php echo site_url(); ?>pro/submit_business";
$.post(url, dataForm).succes(function(data) { alert(); });
```

Comment: I have checked with your code. i need to get the value as json format. uploaded file showing as object

Answer (score 0):

Please check data properly append with formdata.
var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
formData.append('licens_certificate', licens_certificate);

$.ajax({
    url: "pro/submit_business",
    type: "POST",
    data:formData,
    async: false,
    processData : false,
    contentType : false,
    // fileElementId   :'licens_certificate',
    dataType: "json",
    // contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
    success: function(result){
        alert(result)
    }
});